# How can I get bookmarked hash links to work with a jQuery change function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

What's the simplest way with this jQuery change function to get bookmarked hash links to work, i.e. to be able to use `example.com/#theme1` or `example.com/#theme2` links?

The jQuery `#theme-selector` changes the hash and shows/hides the relevant divs with the class, i.e. `.theme1` or `.theme2`, but when going to `example.com/#theme1` from a bookmarked link, all divs are shown.

In addition, if I manually refresh a URL with a hash, i.e. `example.com/#theme1`, the hash remains `#theme1`, but all divs are shown.

Some other questions on SO deal with bookmarkable hashes, but they're many years old. And some libraries that appear useful are ten years old, too, like https://github.com/asual/jquery-address

Unfortunately, running the snippet here won't show browser hash changes, nor will JSFiddle.

```js
  jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery){
    
        jQuery("#theme-selector").change(function () {
    
        var urlhash = document.getElementById('theme-selector').value;
    
        window.location.hash = urlhash;
    
    });
    
    
    jQuery("#theme-selector").change(function () {
    
    themeclass = window.location.hash.substr(1);
    
    jQuery('.blockcontent').hide();
    jQuery('.' +themeclass).show();
    jQuery('.theme-header').hide();
    jQuery('.' +themeclass).show();
    
        });
    
    });
```

```css
 .blockcontent {
    display:inline-block;
    width:150px;
    border:1px solid #acacac;
    }
    
    .theme-header {
    display:none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <label for="theme-selector">Filter by Theme:</label>
    
    <select name="theme-selector" id="theme-selector" value="">
    
    <option value="all-themes">All Themes</option>
    <option value="theme1">Theme 1</option>
    <option value="theme2">Theme 2</option>
    <option value="theme3">Theme 3</option>
    
    </select>
    
    <br>
    
    <div id="theme-description-container">
    <div class="theme1 theme-header">Theme 1 Description</div>
    <div class="theme2 theme-header">Theme 2 Description</div>
    <div class="theme3 theme-header">Theme 3 Description</div>
    </div>
   
    <br>
    
    <div class="blockcontent all-themes theme1">
    theme1<br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do 
    </div>
    
    <div class="blockcontent all-themes theme2">
    theme2<br><br>sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt sed do eiusmod eiusmod
    </div>
    
    <div class="blockcontent all-themes theme3 theme2">
    theme2 and theme3<br><br>consectetur adipiscing elit,consect adipiscing elit, 
    </div>
    
    <div class="blockcontent all-themes theme3">
    theme3<br><br>consectetur adipiscing elit,consect etur adipiscing elit, 
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have encountered this problem many times. This is the solution we use. It will handle the `<select>` changes and will trigger the changes if the theme is part of the `url` from direct links or bookmarked pages etc. Hopefully it is a little more succinct and efficient:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <style>
            .blockcontent {
                display: inline-block;
                width: 150px;
                border: 1px solid #acacac;
            }
    
            .theme-header {
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <label for="theme-selector">Filter by Theme:</label>
        
        <select name="theme-selector" id="theme-selector" value="">
            <option value="all-themes">All Themes</option>
            <option value="theme1">Theme 1</option>
            <option value="theme2">Theme 2</option>
            <option value="theme3">Theme 3</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <div id="theme-description-container">
            <div class="theme1 theme-header">Theme 1 Description</div>
            <div class="theme2 theme-header">Theme 2 Description</div>
            <div class="theme3 theme-header">Theme 3 Description</div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="blockcontent all-themes theme1">
            theme1<br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
        </div>
        <div class="blockcontent all-themes theme2">
            theme2<br><br>sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt sed do eiusmod eiusmod
        </div>
        <div class="blockcontent all-themes theme3 theme2">
            theme2 and theme3<br><br>consectetur adipiscing elit,consect adipiscing elit,
        </div>
        <div class="blockcontent all-themes theme3">
            theme3<br><br>consectetur adipiscing elit,consect etur adipiscing elit,
        </div>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                // Add event listener to theme-selector <select> element
                // Pass in the event object as 'e' variable
                $("#theme-selector").change(function (e) {
                    // themeclass is the option selected value
                    const themeclass = e.target.value;
                    window.location.hash = themeclass;
                    // Select both classes at once. 
                    // No need to do them separately as this involves more DOM searches which is inefficient
                    $('.blockcontent, .theme-header').hide();
                    $('.' + themeclass).show();
                });
        
                // Now that you have an event listener set up handle direct links/bookmarked pages
                const urlhash = window.location.hash;
                if (urlhash !== "") {
                    // Use jQuery val() method to select <option value="urlhash">
                    // Trigger change on that value
                    $('#theme-selector').val(urlhash.slice(1)).trigger('change');
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! That works great. I see what you are doing the event listener. This greatly simplifies what I was using before.

Comment: You're welcome. I tried to adapt my code to your needs as much as possible. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `$(location).attr('hash');` to get the current hash.

I commented my code.

NOTE : instead of using `document.getElementById('theme-selector')`, you can just use `$(this)`.

EDIT : **Change event handler should be defined before calling the .trigger('change')**

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery) {

  
  jQuery("#theme-selector").change(function () {
    var urlhash = document.getElementById('theme-selector').value;
    window.location.hash = urlhash;

  });


 jQuery("#theme-selector").change(function () {

  themeclass = window.location.hash.substr(1);

  jQuery('.blockcontent').hide();
  jQuery('.' +themeclass).show();
  jQuery('.theme-header').hide();
  jQuery('.' +themeclass).show();

 });
 
   var urlhash = $(location).attr('hash'); // current hash
  
  // we check if current hash exist
  if (urlhash && urlhash !== "") {
     urlhash = urlhash.replace('#', ''); // remove # from hash
     
     // trigger change on selected option corresponding to hash
     $("#theme-selector option[value='" + urlhash + "']").prop("selected",true).trigger("change");
  }

});
```

```css
.blockcontent {
    display:inline-block;
    width:150px;
    border:1px solid #acacac;
    }
    
    .theme-header {
    display:none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <label for="theme-selector">Filter by Theme:</label>
    
    <select name="theme-selector" id="theme-selector" value="">
    
    <option value="all-themes">All Themes</option>
    <option value="theme1">Theme 1</option>
    <option value="theme2">Theme 2</option>
    <option value="theme3">Theme 3</option>
    
    </select>
    
    <br>
    
    <div id="theme-description-container">
    <div class="theme1 theme-header">Theme 1 Description</div>
    <div class="theme2 theme-header">Theme 2 Description</div>
    <div class="theme3 theme-header">Theme 3 Description</div>
    </div>
   
    <br>
    
    <div class="blockcontent all-themes theme1">
    theme1<br><br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do 
    </div>
    
    <div class="blockcontent all-themes theme2">
    theme2<br><br>sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt sed do eiusmod eiusmod
    </div>
    
    <div class="blockcontent all-themes theme3 theme2">
    theme2 and theme3<br><br>consectetur adipiscing elit,consect adipiscing elit, 
    </div>
    
    <div class="blockcontent all-themes theme3">
    theme3<br><br>consectetur adipiscing elit,consect etur adipiscing elit, 
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I see what you changed and it works the same as my original code. But the problem is still that I can't go to example.com/#theme1 in a new tab or different browser and see only divs with the theme1 class; I see all divs. Do we need to "refire" the jQuery to hide/show divs according to the hash?

Comment: Im sorry, change event handler should be defined before calling the .trigger('change')... Now it works @BlueDogRanch

Comment: Thanks, still no luck. In addition, if I refresh example.com/#theme1, the hash stays the same, but I see all divs. So something isn't firing or following the hash.

Comment: Please grad all my code below and try again. I did it just now and it works even if u refresh. @BlueDogRanch

Comment: Thanks for the help! My mistake, that does work in an index.html file on my desktop. I was only trying it on my live server, where for some reason it doesn't work. I added an update 10/26/23 to my question with more info and a link to older, plain Javascript that does work. What is it in the plain Javascript that works and can be adapted to the jQuery?